# Using apache2, how to redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www. to www. (and all the possible combinations)

Tags: ubuntu, mod-rewrite, server, apache2

I have an SSL certificate for a website that starts with www. And when I try to access without https it goes to the default apache page and when I try to access without the www it shows that the page has no valid certification. I would like all of the following variations...

- `example.com`
- `www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`

lead to `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Is this your own server? By the sounds of it, you need more than a "simple" redirect as it sounds like your server (or virtualhost) is not configured properly? Presumably you do have a website set up? "when I try to access without https it goes to the default apache page" - when you go to the plain HTTP version you should still see your website, not the "default Apache page", unless you've not configured your HTTP vHost at all?

Comment: "when I try to access without the www it shows that the page has no valid certification" - Your SSL cert needs to include the domain apex!? Only once you have fixed these issues can you consider implementing a redirect.